# Launch Casper from Node and pass it JSON

Tags: node.js, casperjs

I'm attempting the programmatic transfer of a website from one CMS to another, and the APIs for both are either broken or non-existent. Poking around directly in the databases seems complicated so I need to scrape data from one site and enter it into the admin interface of the other.

My prototype uses JSDOM to scrape and Casper to fill in the forms. JSDOM for scraping as it's much faster than Casper (important to me because my hardware is old and I might want to have frequently run end-to-end tests. Also I want to be able to do normal Node stuff as part of the scrape.)

Casper sits in its own process (and I can't get Spooky working). I've not a clue about interprocess communication, but copied a `spawn()` example from the Node docs. So once the scrape is complete, Node launches Casper.

The scrape routines will eventually produce a whole lot of JSON. To pass this to Casper, ATM with my prototype -which works on only a few sample pages -I'm just passing the JSON in to the subprocess as a command line argument.

Hopefully this will be fine because running `xargs --show-limits` gives me:

```
Your environment variables take up 2914 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2092190
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2089276
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
Maximum parallelism (--max-procs must be no greater): 2147483647
```

so I guess I've about a two million character limit on the JSON string, which I hope to be well over what I need.

Is there anything I'm not considering that might hamper things as I scale up to deal with lots of JSON data? (Hard to say how much there'd be).